# Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster,

Tags: r, terra

```r
> for(nc_file in pkulist){
+      nc_date <- rast(nc_file, lyrs = 1)
+      raster_list[[length(raster_list) + 1]]<- nc_date
+  }
Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: ./PKU_GIMMS_NDVI_AVHRR_MODIS_consolidated_1991_2000/PKU_GIMMS_NDVI_V1.2_20000801.tif.aux.xml
In addition: Warning message:
`./PKU_GIMMS_NDVI_AVHRR_MODIS_consolidated_1991_2000/PKU_GIMMS_NDVI_V1.2_20000801.tif.aux.xml' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4) 
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Seems that your file list `pkulist` includes not only `*.tif` files but also auxiliary files ( `*.tif.aux.xml` ); you might want to take a few steps back and re-check the code that you have not included in your question, i.e the part where you create `pkulist` , and make sure it only includes raster files.  Or if you don't use aux files, you could just remove those from raster folder.

Comment: ` pkulist <- `list.files('/my_pku_files/dir/dir', pattern = '.tif$', full.names = TRUE)` will list tif files but exclude .tif.aux.xml as the `$` say 'files that end with ,tif', and this will likely clean up your list for further processing.

Comment: I'm a beginner in R, so thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages seems very clear. You are trying to create a raster from a file that does not represent raster data (it is a "sidecar" file to a proper raster file).

As Chris points out, you could do something like

```
ff <- list.files(pattern = '.tif$')
```

Followed by

```
x <- rast(ff)
```

or perhaps

```
x <- rast(lapply(ff, \(f) rast(f, lyrs=1)))
```